# Tombstone question for SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

So far, I know that change tracking is integrated with SQL Server 2008, and it's being done automatically. What I don't know is whether I should modify the schema by appending a "_tombstone" myself or it's being done automatically by the server.

Right now when I'm attempting to access the tombstone table from the server. It results in an `SqlException` saying that the table could not be found.

How do I access the values of the change tracking values created by SQL Server 2008 from C#?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replied to your similar question.  In summary, it may be easier to use the SQL Server Management Studio, Object Explorer to see what tables are created.

UPDATE
The next step would be to use SQL Server Profiler to capture SQL statements that are submitted to the SQL Server.  You should alter the default trace settings to include Events RPC:Starting and SQL:BatchStarting instead of the existing events.

Comment: tombstone table is not created. so the ultimate question is how does sql server 2008 implement change tracking? In a sense of where is the tombstone table, of where does it save the changes ...

Comment: Change tracking is not enabled by default.  And, it is designed to capture data changes, not DDL changes.  See answer for additional suggestion